# Memory warning issue and app shut down

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5

I have a problem with a memory warning that causes my app to suddenly shut down. I need to know how this memory warning problem can be removed from my project. I'm working on a game project which contains 250 images having 94kb, and i'm displaying these images in an imageView by picking each one randomly through the press of a button. The image names are stored in the plist and I also had added the images on the xcode. The app also shuts down when the these images which I had displayed in a view is passed to the gameOversection by displaying the images that had displayed on the previous view.

Comment: Memory warnings cannot be removed, they are controlled by the OS

Comment: You want to give us some more details or is it more of a guessing game?

Comment: You should understand WHY you have a memory warning. use instruments, understand where you have a bottle neck, understand which method kills your memory. Is the project in ARC or MRC? You must be able to localize and describe your problem if you want to do this job.

Answer (score 3):

Your application is using too much memory, and iOS is shutting it off. The solution is to reduce your memory usage, and respond to the memory warnings by releasing anything you don't need. You may also have memory leaks running up your usage.

Here are a few links that might be helpful:

- [Memory Usage Performance Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/ManagingMemory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000160i)
- [WWDC 2013: Fixing Memory Issues](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/?id=410)
- [WWDC 2012: iOS App Performance: Memory](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=242)